# How to avoid this NOT IN clause?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I Have three tables:

**The scenario**

```
|  users |         | teams_users |      | teams |
 --------           -------------        -------
|   id   |         |   user_id   |      |   id  |
                   |   team_id   | 
                   | begin_date  |
                   |  end_date   |
```

So. If a user is assigned to a team, a new `team_users` registry id created, and the `end_date` is null.

If a user is pulled of a team, the `end_date` is filled with the current date.

**Why is that way?**

Because there's need to keep the history of that user in that team.

**The Problem**

When I'm creating/editing a team, I want to present a list of available users for that team. That list should follow these rules:

- The user can't be in the current team
- The user can be on another team
- The user can have a team_user registry, with a end_date != null

**The solution so far**

I'm using rails 2.3.14 (Don't ask!). My solution so far is:

```
#team_id is the current team

users_on_this_team = TeamUser.all(
   :conditions => {:team_id => team_id, :end_date => nil}
).collect { |team_user| team_user.user_id }

User.all(:conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", users_on_this_team]
```

Which works, but it feels hacky. I'm trying to came up with a better solution, maybe using JOIN, but I'm stuck.

Any ideias?

Comment: Looks good to me. All users that are NOT IN this team. So the code resembles how one would word the task. Perfect in my opinion.

Comment: Also - I guess that the number of users in teams is relatively small so this will be translated to a small list and the DB can do it all in memory. I agree with Thorsten, it doesn't look problematic to me. Do you see any performance issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`arel` gem](https://github.com/rails/arel), which allow to advance the query:

```
ids = TeamUser.select("DISTINCT teams_users.user_id")
               .where(team_id: team_id, end_date: nil)
User.where(User.arel_table[:id].not_in(ids))
```

but I guess, the better way is to use the specific scope:

```
class User
   belongs_to :team_user

   scope :outteam_users, ->{ joins(team_user).where(TeamUser.
            arel_table[:user_id].not_eq(User.arel_table[:id]) }
end
```

Please **note** that both queries are unconformed.